# FastApi getting 422 error instead 201 in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I'm kinda new to python and FastApi. I'm running some pytests and I'm getting a 422 response instread of a 201.

Here's the code.

```
pizza_type_dict = \
    {
        'name': 'Salami Pizza',
        'price': 2.50,
        'description': 'Italian style'
    }


def create_sauce_for_pizza_type():
    response = client.post(
        "/v1/sauces",
        json={"name": "Spicy sauce", "price": 0.5, "description": "good sauce", "stock": 10},
    )
    assert response.status_code == 201
    response_body = response.json()
    pizza_type_dict['sauce_id'] = response_body['id']


def test_create_pizza_type():
    response = client.post(
        "/v1/pizza-types",
        json=pizza_type_dict
    )
    assert response.status_code == 201
    response_body = response.json()
    assert response_body['name'] == 'Salami Pizza'
    assert response_body['price'] == 2.50
    assert response_body['description'] == 'Italian style'

    pizza_type_dict['id'] = response_body['id']
```

The sauces class has an id(uuid) as attribute and the pizza_type class has a sauce_id as attribute. The thing is when I declare an existing
uuid in pizza_type_dict the test works. Is it a python dict problem?

Comment: who calls the ```create_sauce_for_pizza_type``` function? I will suggest to move that to a fixture

Comment: Which one fails, what does it says, please also share them, what your endpoint looks like, etc.